# Convert Polars dataframe to vector of structs

Tags: rust-polars, maturin

I am making a Maturin project involving Polars on both the Python and Rust side.

In Python I have a dataframe with columns `a` and `b`:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': ['foo', 'bar']})
```

In Rust I have a struct `MyStruct` with the fields `a` and `b`:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  a: i64
  b: String
}
```

I would like to convert each row in the dataframe to an instance of `MyStruct`, mapping the dataframe to a vector of `MyStruct`s. This should be done *on the Rust side*.

I can get this done on the Python side (assuming `MyStruct` is exposed as a `pyclass`). First by getting a list of Python dicts and then constructing a Python list of `MyStruct`.

```py
df_as_list = df.to_struct'MyStruct').to_list()
[MyStruct(**x) for x in df_as_list]
```

To spice things up a bit more, imagine that `MyStruct` has an enum field instead of a `String` field:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
  Foo
  Bar
}
```

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  a: i64
  b: MyEnum
}
```

With a suitable function `string_to_myenum` that maps strings to `MyEnum` (that is, "foo" to `Foo` and "bar" to `Bar`) it would be great to map the dataframe to the new `MyStruct`.